# PHP regex - replace but get numeric value from replaced string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have some HTML that contains multiple HTML comments, within each comment is a form. I am trying to use preg_replace to replace these comments and the forms within with a tag in the form [CONTACT_FORM_X] where X is the numeric ID of the form.

```
$str = 'blah blah blah <!-- CONTACT FORM START [CONTACT_FORM_1] -->some form goes here<!-- CONTACT FORM END 1 --> blah blah blah <!-- CONTACT FORM START [CONTACT_FORM_2] -->another form goes here<!-- CONTACT FORM END 2 -->';

$replace = preg_replace('/<!-- CONTACT FORM START \[CONTACT_FORM_\d\] -->.*<!-- CONTACT FORM END \d -->/', '[CONTACT_FORM_X]', $str);
echo $replace;
```

So:

```
<!-- CONTACT FORM START [CONTACT_FORM_1] -->some form goes here<!-- CONTACT FORM END 1 -->
```

Should be replaced entirely with [CONTACT_FORM_1]

And ..

```
<!-- CONTACT FORM START [CONTACT_FORM_2] --> another form goes here<!-- CONTACT FORM END 2 -->
```

Should be replaced entirely with [CONTACT_FORM_2]

If I run my code above I get:

```
blah blah blah [CONTACT_FORM_X]
```

So my questions are:

1. How can I get the value of \d and then use this in place of where I currently use X in my preg_replace
2. My code only seems to replace one of the forms rather than both occurrences. How can I adapt preg_replace to allow multiple replaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `preg_replace` will replace all occurrences (it is global). The `.*` is greedy though and is matching everything after the `<!-- CONTACT FORM START \[CONTACT_FORM_(\d)\]` until `<!-- CONTACT FORM END \d -->`. To capture a value use `()`.

So try:

```
.*?<!-- CONTACT FORM START \[CONTACT_FORM_(\d)\] -->.*?<!-- CONTACT FORM END \d -->
```

or if you want to be sure you are matching the same closing contact form use the backreference:

```
.*?<!-- CONTACT FORM START \[CONTACT_FORM_(\d)\] -->.*?<!-- CONTACT FORM END \1 -->
```

The leading `.*?` should be removed if the preceding content should be kept. It is unclear to me what the intent is with that bit. From the `Should be replaced entirely with [CONTACT_FORM_2]` I interpreted as that's the only content that should remain.

Regex demo: https://regex101.com/r/kS2nK6/1

PHP Usage:

```
<?php
$str = 'blah blah blah <!-- CONTACT FORM START [CONTACT_FORM_1] -->some form goes here<!-- CONTACT FORM END 1 --> blah blah blah <!-- CONTACT FORM START [CONTACT_FORM_2] -->another form goes here<!-- CONTACT FORM END 2 -->';

$replace = preg_replace('/.*?<!-- CONTACT FORM START \[CONTACT_FORM_(\d)\] -->.*?<!-- CONTACT FORM END \d -->/', '[CONTACT_FORM_$1]', $str);
echo $replace;
```

PHP Demo: https://eval.in/611232

Answer (score 1):

Change your pattern and your replacement string as below:

```
$pattern = '/<!-- CONTACT FORM START \[CONTACT_FORM_(\d+)\] -->.*<!-- CONTACT FORM END \1 -->/';
$replace = preg_replace($pattern, '[CONTACT_FORM_$1]', $str);
```

[**Live demo**](https://3v4l.org/fSkXE)

**How it works**

- Put in parentheses any text you want to reuse later. This is called a *captured group*. So I changed `\d` to `(\d+)` in your pattern (the `+` just allows double-digit+ numbers)
- To refer back to the first captured group from within the pattern, use `\1`. Changing `CONTACT FORM END \d` to `CONTACT FORM END \1` tells the regex engine that the string to replace stops as soon as you hit the `END` with the same number you saw in `START`.  Without this, the engine replaces everything to the very last `CONTACT FORM END`. That's why you were getting just one replacement.
- In the replacement string, use `$1` to refer to the first captured group. That's why changing `CONTACT_FORM_X` to `CONTACT_FORM_$1` places the right number in the replacement string.

Comment: @chris85 you're right. I have. The `Should be replaced entirely` references a substring that doesn't include `blah blah blah` (check the OP again)

Comment: Oh, unclear in that case. I'll add note to my answer as well.